# First-Order Structure Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

M is a model with domain M(∀) = {1, 2, 3} and

• M(a) = 1, M(b) = 3, M(c) = 2

• M(P) = {1, 3}, M(R) = {(3, 1),(2, 2),(2, 1),(3, 3)}
h is a variable assignment with h(x) = 2, h(y) = 3, and h(z) = 2.

For each of the
following statements, determine whether it is true or false. Explain your answers by
following the definition of satisfaction step by step.

I'm having trouble with the following two statements:

1) M |= R(c, y)[h[y/1]]

2) M |= c = x ∧ R(y, x)[h]

Appreciating all input.

Comment: In your 2nd bullet point "M(R) = {h3, 1i,h2, 2i,h2, 1i,h3, 3i}" -- what does this mean? what is "i"? M(R) should be a set of ordered pairs, it would help if you presented it as such.

Comment: Apologies: stupid typo. I edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks little less cluttered (and it's standard usage) to use $M$ as a superscript on symbols, indicating "the interpretation of (that symbol) in the model $M$". 
Thus, $c^M = M(c) = 2$, and $R^M = M(R)$, etc.

#### 1) True

I take it that $h[y/1]$ means "the map which agrees with $h$ everywhere except at '$y$' where its value is $1$".

We need to check whether a particular ordered pair is in $R^M$, namely, whether or not
$$
(c^M, h[y/1](y)) \in R^M
$$
By definition, $h[y/1](y) = 1$, and $c^M = 2$, so 1) is true provided
$$
(2,1) \in R^M
$$
Checking your definition of $R^M = M(R)$, this is the case.

#### 2) False

$M \models (c = x \wedge R(y,x))[h]$ is true *iff* both of the following are true:
$$M \models (c = x)[h] \tag{2a}
$$
and
$$M \models R(y,x)[h] \tag{2b} \text{.}
$$
(2a) is true *iff* $c^M = h(x)$; as $c^M = 2$ and $h(x) = 2$, they are equal.

(2b) is true *iff*  $(h(y), h(x)) \in R^M$. But $(h(y), h(x)) = (3,2) \notin R^M$, so (2b) is false, thus 2) is false.